# quiz with choices using datareader. clicking button to change from number 1 to 4

Tags: c#, sql

click a button to change the question in my Form and choices.. but this code only shows the last data of my table when i click it

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JOSHMAV-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * "+
                                            "FROM question", conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(reader["C1"].ToString());
                ques.Text = reader["ques"].ToString();
                radioButton1.Text = reader["C1"].ToString();
                radioButton2.Text = reader["C2"].ToString();
                radioButton3.Text = reader["C3"].ToString();
                radioButton4.Text = reader["C4"].ToString();


            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

im only starting in sql server

Comment: This is logical as you loop through the records with reader.Read() and you assign each record to the radioButtons in the while loop. So last record is shown.

Comment: Move the code to read the data to the form load . at the end of radioButton4. Text add a break. This is only to show you have it works. Later you can take out the while.

Comment: in order to change it put into you query some statetmen to check like  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * "+
                                            "FROM question where id ="+one, conn) where one is int type of value and increment or decrement it somewhere of your program;

Comment: @Aldert that only means i can view the question number 1 but not really answers the question.. thanks anyways

Comment: That totally depends how you program it. When you add to your question what you try to achieve people can help you better.

Comment: @Aldert it's on the title.. from question 1 i want to go to question 2 and so on until the last row of my table.. it is a quiz with choices as radio buttons

Comment: OK, I try to explain again: Declare the reader in the form class, including the connection stuff. In the Load of the form, instanciate objects. untill. command.ExecuteReader(). Your reader is now open. Change the while to an if. place the reader.Close() in the else.

Answer (score 0):

you should add some int type of data and you should check it from you sql statement then
you can get your willing data from database it something like this

don't forget to increment it in somewhere of you program and keep in mind of boundary of it

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JOSHMAV-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * "+
                                            "FROM question where id ="+one, conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Form1
    {   
        private SqlConnection conn;
        private SqlCommand command;
        private SqlDataReader reader;
    public Form1()
    {

     conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JOSHMAV-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True");
     command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * "+ "FROM question", conn);
     try
     {
          conn.Open();
          reader = command.ExecuteReader();
     }
      catch (SqlException ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
     }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(reader["C1"].ToString());
                    ques.Text = reader["ques"].ToString();
                    radioButton1.Text = reader["C1"].ToString();
                    radioButton2.Text = reader["C2"].ToString();
                    radioButton3.Text = reader["C3"].ToString();
                    radioButton4.Text = reader["C4"].ToString();


                }
            else reader.Close();
            }


        }
```

Comment: You will have an open connection so it would be a better idea to create a class mapping to the fields you ned and put the in the form load in a list. Then you can step through the list. This example is only to show concept